# How to reliably determine the width of a character in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, fonts, width, fixed-width

I'm writing a C# program and I'm using a fixed-width font to display everything. Under this font, every Unicode character either occupies 1 character width or 2 character width. In the program, there is a feature that needs to determine a particular character occupies 1 character width or 2 character  width. At first I use the regex `[^\x00-\xFF]` to solve the problem. If a character matches it, it occupies 1 character width, otherwise it's 2 character width. But later I found this is not correct. For example, these characters `┌─┬┐│├┼┤┴┘` don't fall in the range of `[^\x00-\xFF]` but they all just occupies 1 character width. I want to know in C# how to determine a specific character occupies 1 character width or 2 when using fixed-width font?

Comment: There are many unicode glyphs that occupy 0 space. For example there is the https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks block in Unicode that is composed of glyphs that are superimposed to the previous glyph. As another sidenote many unicode glyphs are made of two C# `char` (all the non-BMP glyphs, the ones with code > 0xFFFF). Sadly `Regex` in .NET doesn't support the non-BMP part of Unicode

Comment: have you considered rendering the characters and measuring the result with either [`Graphics.MeasureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=net-5.0) or [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @timur The application I'm writing is a console app. To render it and then measure the text is way too heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also searching for the same question's answer... but I haven't found it.
by the way, I finally write a library to get length of character (generate a range information which shows character length use Console.Write() and Console.CursorLeft, and then convert to C# code, when get character length, use binary search for higher speed)

nuget: NullLib.ConsoleEx
Project: https://github.com/SlimeNull/NullLib.ConsoleEx

Comment: This looks interesting! I'll take a look. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score -1):

According to .NET documentation, if you know the font used<sup>1</sup>, you could use the [GlyphTypeface API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface?view=net-5.0) to [get the *"AdvanceWidths"* of each glyph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.advancewidths?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Media_GlyphTypeface_AdvanceWidths) of your font.

You still have to map the character with glyph index in your font. You can use [`CharacterToGlyphMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.charactertoglyphmap?view=net-5.0) to do that.

```cs
var character = 'x';

GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri("file:///C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Kooten.ttf"));

var index = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[character];
var width = glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[index];
```

<sup>[1]</sup> To get current console's font details I would recommend to read following question: [Get current console font info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428050/get-current-console-font-info)

Related question: [How to find exact size for an arbitrary glyph in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971547/how-to-find-exact-size-for-an-arbitrary-glyph-in-wpf)